# Why doesn't the transpose change the array?

Tags: python, numpy

```
y = np.array([1, 1, 0, 0])
print("Y 1:", y)
y = y.T

print("Y 2:", y)
```

Both print the same:

```
[1,1,0,0]
```

The numpy array `a = [1,1,0,0]` shape is `[4,]` and `b= [[1,1,0,0]]` is `[1,4]`. Can I say that a is a vector and b is a matrix. So the transpose operation doesn't work for vector so the two prints are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

numpy distinguishes 1d "vectors" from 2d "row vectors" and "column vectors".  it's common to switch between them using something like:

```
# create 1d vector
v = np.array([1, 1, 0, 0])

# row vector
rv = v[np.newaxis, :]

# column vector
cv = v[:, np.newaxis]
```

note that [`np.newaxis` is defined to be `None`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis), so you'll often see this written as, e.g. `v[:,None]` and because needing a column vector is such a common operation there are obscure shorthands like [`np.c_[v]`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.c_.html)

now that `rv` and `cv` are 2d they can be [transposed](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.transpose.html) as you were expecting

switching back to a 1d vector is similar:

```
# from row vector
v = rv[0, :]

# from column vector
v = cv[:, 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from the documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html), transposing a 1-D array returns an unchanged view of the original array. In your case, `y` is a 1-D array, hence the transposed output will be unchanged.

Comment: [[1,1,0,0]], the shape is (1,4). How many dimensions for this? also one?

Comment: if you have ````y = np.array([[1, 1, 0, 0]])```` your shape will be (1,4) meaning 2 dimensions, your tranposed array will have (4,1)

Comment: @ling the number of dimensions is just the length of the shape, i.e. `len(y.shape)`